# How to transfer sql table value to mongoDB using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

I need one help . I have some value in mysql table and i need it to transfer to MongoDB collection using script in Node.js.I am explaining my table below.

> db_user(mysql):

```
id    name        email                    address

 1    Raj       raj@gmail.com               USA

 2    Rocky     rk@gmail.com                UK
```

The above is the  mysql table and i need those value to my mongoDB collection which is given below.

> db_user(MongoDB):

```
_id     name     email        address
```

Here i need when i will run the script the mysql table values will transfer to my mongoDB collection. please help me.

Comment: at first why do you need it in Node.js? do you need to do it once or continuously, if second, then please show how you tried to do it (reading from mysql and instring into mongo), and if you need to do it once you just need to convert mysql data to json and then impont it into mongo

Comment: did you try convert the rows to respective `JSON` object(one row will become one `object`) and then just need to insert in `mongodb`

Comment: @2oppin : Yes, i need those data are not present in mongo those will transfer no duplicate data allowed.